# How do I resolve "the type is not accessible" error in Eclipse when using an external JAR? JAR in question is algs4 from Princeton

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm taking a CS 2420 Algorithms and Data Structures course based on the Princeton class taught by Prof. Sedgewick. I'm doing a team project where we I need to implement a GUI. My partner finished the back end classes and I'm trying to bring them into my GUI project folder and implement them. The classes use references to other classes in algs4 and stdlib. I'm getting errors on the import statements that say "The type edu.princeton.cs.algs4.Queue is not accessible". However, I have configured the build path to match my other project folder that uses them and I'm still getting the import errors. Is there something I need to do in the build path configuration that will resolve this? Screenshots attached.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Here's the build path:
[image: Build Path]

I've also tried cleaning the project, closing and opening Eclipse, using an online tutor, re-configuring the build path, etc.

Comment: Either a) delete your `module-info.java` or - b) use the quick fix to add `requires algs4` to the module-info.java and move algs4.jar to the module-path.

Comment: Oh my goodness dude, that was so simple! I deleted `module-info.java` and that resolved it! Thank you so much! Do you wanna put that as the official answer so I can mark it as such? To get rep?